# Is it possible to turn a "while True: with x as y:" into a "while x as y" loop in python?

Tags: python

I was wondering if it was possible to join a `with` and `while True` loop, since `while True` is very simple (just runs until something breaks it), and kind of wastes an indent.

This is some example code as I'd currently do it:

```
class Something(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 5
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        pass

while True:
    with Something() as s:
        print s.num
```

If possible, how would I change it to something similar to this?

```
while Something() as s:
    print s.num
```

Comment: No, and that's a really weird choice of syntactical constructs to merge.

Answer (score 2):

No, because your suggestion is not compatible with the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html) for a while statement:

```
while_stmt: 'while' test ':' suite ['else' ':' suite]
```

That's documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement).  Python is not as hackable as, say, ruby in terms of grammar.

Since it's part of the language reference, you could only change it by modifying python sources.   Then you have to compile your own interpreter and you are no longer using the python language, by definition.

Comment: I knew the particular syntax wouldn't work, but wasn't sure if something else might do, like a `next()` function (I've never used it so don't know how it works) or something.